# Simple jQuery custom wizard form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to manage some quiz test in jquery and html, that load automatically on same page but I have problems on div Q2, its load every time same question. 
How can I manage this script to work fine, I'm try almost everything on my mind but still cant do it.

Here is jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#q2").fadeOut("fast");
 $("#q3").fadeOut("fast");
 $("#q4").fadeOut("fast");

document.getElementById('q1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  $("#q1").fadeOut();
  $("#q2").fadeIn();
 }, false); 

document.getElementById('q2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  $("#q2").fadeOut();
  $("#q3").fadeIn();
 }, false); 

document.getElementById('q3').addEventListener('click', function() {
  $("#q3").fadeOut();
  $("#q4").fadeIn();
 }, false); 

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="q1">               
 <div class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio1" class="css-checkbox" />
   <label for="radio1" class="css-label">answer1</label>
 </div>
 <div class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio2" class="css-checkbox" />
   <label for="radio2" class="css-label">answer2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="q2">               
 <div class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio3" class="css-checkbox" />
   <label for="radio3" class="css-label">answer3</label>
 </div>
 <div class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio4" class="css-checkbox" />
   <label for="radio4" class="css-label">answer4</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="q3">               
 <div class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio5" class="css-checkbox" />
   <label for="radio5" class="css-label">answer5</label>
 </div>
 <div class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio6" class="css-checkbox" />
   <label for="radio6" class="css-label">answer6</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="q4">               
 <div class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio7" class="css-checkbox" />
   <label for="radio7" class="css-label">answer7</label>
 </div>
 <div class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio8" class="css-checkbox" />
   <label for="radio8" class="css-label">answer8</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know this is not probably best way to do it, but dont have idea how manage on right way. I still learning and if you know how to do it, I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems I see with the way you're trying to do this:

- All your radio inputs have the same `name` attribute. Radio input grouping is defined by their name, so you'd want a unique name for every set of radio belonging to a question.
- Your code is really rigid. As questions are added or removed a change in your javascript code is required.

I'd rewrite it to something like this:

First, add a class to each of your question divs, ie: `question`:

```
<div id="q1" class="question">
```

As for your javascript code:

```
// this variable will hold a list of all questions in the page (identified by the class 'question')
var $questions = $(".question");

// all questions start out hidden
$questions.hide();

// show the first question
$questions.first().fadeIn("fast");

// when a radio input is changed
$("input[type='radio']").on("change", function() {
    // remove the first question from the questions list and hide it
    var question = $questions.splice(0, 1);
    $(question).hide();

    // show the (now new) first question (if there are any left)
    $questions.first().length && $questions.first().fadeIn("fast"); 
});
```

```js
var $questions = $(".question");

// hide all questions
$questions.hide();

// show the first question
$questions.first().fadeIn("fast");

$("input[type='radio']").on("change", function() {
  // remove the first question from the questions list and hide it
  var question = $questions.splice(0, 1);
  $(question).hide();

  // show the (now new) first question in our list (if there are any left)
  $questions.first().length && $questions.first().fadeIn("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="q1" class="question">
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio1" class="css-checkbox" />
    <label for="radio1" class="css-label">answer1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark" id="radio2" class="css-checkbox" />
    <label for="radio2" class="css-label">answer2</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="q2" class="question">
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark2" id="radio3" class="css-checkbox" />
    <label for="radio3" class="css-label">answer3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark2" id="radio4" class="css-checkbox" />
    <label for="radio4" class="css-label">answer4</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="q3" class="question">
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark3" id="radio5" class="css-checkbox" />
    <label for="radio5" class="css-label">answer5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark3" id="radio6" class="css-checkbox" />
    <label for="radio6" class="css-label">answer6</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="q4" class="question">
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark4" id="radio7" class="css-checkbox" />
    <label for="radio7" class="css-label">answer7</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radiog_dark4" id="radio8" class="css-checkbox" />
    <label for="radio8" class="css-label">answer8</label>
  </div>
</div>
```